# Adding From statement to Join statements

Tags: sql, sql-server

So the code has multiple join statements, and all I need to add is a where clause that checks one value. The table I need to reference is not used in the From statement which includes multiple joins. Is there anyway to add a regular FROM statement without disrupting the JOINS

```
SELECT    D.data
          H.otherData
FROM
          Dada AS D
JOIN      Haha AS H
          ON D.ID = H.ID
WHERE    
          C.Value = x --This is what I want to do. Can I add another from statement that doesn't affect the join statement
```

Comment: you can add an other `JOIN` on the `C` table, or add a correlated query or .. Can you provide sample data and desired output ? Without all the rules and elements, our answer can not best fit your needs

Comment: Why would you want to do that?   It would be meaningless.

Comment: The question, as you've phrased it, doesn't make any sense. What relationship does C.Value have to the rest of the data in your query? That relationship will tell you (and/or us) how to incorporate it. Please read this post, then edit your question with additional information. https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: maybe you're looking for an outer apply ? something like this `OUTER APPLY (SELECT [Value] FROM ValueTable WHERE ...yourconditions) C` then you do `C.Value = x` where x is some sort of a variable or another field.

Answer (score 3):

Not possible without including C somewhere.

What you're saying is equivalent to "List all the Countries where the Person is called Tom"

Comment: Is there anyway to add the C table in the FROM statement without making it part of the JOIN

Comment: You need a semi join operation, which can be implemented without the JOIN keyword by using IN or EXISTS in the where clause. But inside the IN or the EXISTS< you STILL have to mention C.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `C` table, but it has to be with a `JOIN`. Maybe you want a `CROSS JOIN`, which is the cartesian product of the joining tables against this new table `C` and doesn't require any condition (you can filter the results with a `WHERE` condition).

```
SELECT    D.data
          H.otherData
FROM
          Dada AS D
JOIN      Haha AS H
          ON D.ID = H.ID
CROSS JOIN C
WHERE    
          C.Value = x
```

In this particular, case it would be the same as:

```
SELECT    D.data
          H.otherData
FROM
          Dada AS D
JOIN      Haha AS H
          ON D.ID = H.ID
JOIN      C
          ON C.Value = x
```

If you want to filter the first `JOIN` depending on a value from `C` then you need to put the condition on a subquery on the `WHERE`, like an `IN` or `EXISTS`. There has to be some correlation (a column or expression that both share) between your first `JOIN` and this table `C`, otherwise there is no point in filtering.

For example:

```
SELECT    D.data
          H.otherData
FROM
          Dada AS D
JOIN      Haha AS H
          ON D.ID = H.ID

WHERE     EXISTS (SELECT 'value exists on table C' FROM C WHERE C.Value = D.data)
```